# Default handler for a functional class in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-hooks, prototypejs

I wanted to know if it is possible to have a functional class have a default call method. Let me elaborate.

```
function Foo(){
  /*some logic*/
  Foo.prototype.aletUser = function alertUser(message) {
    alert(message);
  }
}
```

Assume that the code above is my functional class (if my naming for the above structure is wrong please tell me), and i instantiated one of this structure.

```
let param = new Foo();
```

Now, i wish to call the following and hope for it to call my prototype `Foo.alertUser`

```
param('Hey There')
```

How can this be achieved? Thanks in advance.

---

**More insight behind my approach**

I am working with React Native and i wish to have `param('Hey There')` use a hook inside the function but i am out of ideas, i know how to make it work with JavaScript classes, but unfortunately hooks can not be called inside class components.

Comment: You want `param.alertUser('Hey There')`. But this feels wrong in React or modern JS, this is the "old way" to make "classes", if you want to do that then just use the `class` keyword. (And even doing it this way, you would normally put the `Foo.prototype.alertUser` definition *outside* the `Foo` function.)

Comment: I've answered the question you actually asked below, but I suggest you post a new question showing a [mcve] of your situation with the class component and wanting to call a hook. The real solution here is probably not to find a way to shoehorn a hook call into a class component's lifecycle (it's unlikely to work properly). So if you show the situation (in a different question), we can probably help you resolve it without doing it this way.

Answer (score 0):

Answering the question you actually asked, it's possible but probably not a good idea. One way to do it is to have `new Foo` create a function and then *change* its prototype (which is normally not a good idea), like this:

```js
function Foo() {
    // Create a function, the change its prototype to
    // `Foo.prototype` and return it
    const retval = function alertUser(param) {
        console.log(param);
    };
    Object.setPrototypeOf(retval, Foo.prototype);
    return retval;
}
// Make `Foo.prototype` use `Function.prototype` as its prototype
Foo.prototype = Object.create(Function.prototype);
Foo.prototype.constructor = Foo;


const param = new Foo();
param("Hi there");
```

---

**But**, again, that's probably not a good idea, for a couple of reasons:

- Changing an object's prototype can deoptimize the JavaScript engine's implementation of it. Now, it may not matter for what you're using this for, it depends on whether it's critical path (and the degree that the deoptimization is noticeable), so it's certainly an option.
- You've said you're trying to do this so you can use a hook in a class component. As I said in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64086992/default-handler-for-a-functional-class-in-javascript/64087049#comment113326796_64086992), that's probably not going to work and even if it does, it's probably not your best solution

I would step back and say if you find yourself wanting to call a hook from a class component, your best bet is to either:

1. Build class-based functionality equivalent to the hook and don't use the hook, or
2. Change the class component to a functional component so you can use the hook in the normal way

Comment: You could also do 3.  Use composition and you can just mix functional and class based components.

Comment: @Keith - Yeah, I had the impression for whatever reason that wasn't possible, but maybe it was just overlooked. Hopefully the OP does post that other question and we can help them solve the problem -- perhaps with composition. :-)