# Best practice to make a functional entity return both an Object & a Function

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-redux, react-hooks

This question is an elaboration for my other question [Default handler for a functional class in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64086992/default-handler-for-a-functional-class-in-javascript).

I am trying to build a redux action component, something initialized on startup with some configurations and then executed on runtime to dispatch a certain action.

```
import {useDispatch} from 'react-redux';

function ReduxAction(id, config) {
  /*some logic*/
}

ReduxAction.prototype.call = function call() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  dispatch({ type: 'test_action', payload: {} });
  console.log('Redux Action dispatched');
}
```

Here is my defined ReduxAction, outside of any react component.

```
const doTest = new ReduxAction('test', { payload: 'Test' });
```

And in the snippet below, the action is being called with a certain input `{ email: '', password: '' }` in this case.

```
const LoginScreen = () => {
  const onTestPress = () => doTest({ email: '', password: '' });

  return <Button onPress={onTestPress}/>
}
```

**Expected Behavior:**
Action `{ type: 'test', payload: { email: '', password: '' } }` to be dispatched.

**Main concern:**
The reason why i am trying to call my action like this is to avoid importing `useDispatch` and using `const dispatch = useDispatch()` in each component i am planning to dispatch an action from. Thus i wanted to place the `useDispatch` one step higher before calling my ReduxAction with its corresponding payload. Any ideas?

Any feedback over the technique to solve this is more than welcome. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you avoiding useDispatch?

Comment: @evolutionxbox No specific reason but two less lines of code and one less import.

Comment: But if it does what you want, isn't that worth the extra few lines?

Comment: @evolutionxbox true, it does. I actually decided to keep using `useDispatch`, thanks anyways.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't help with the other solution.